# How to vector-derivate this matrix-vector multiplication?

Tags: matrix-calculus, spline

Edit: Possible error in the book? See bottom

I'm reading "Functional Data Analysis" by Ramsay & Silverman. The text contains the following (p. 87), regarding how smoothing spline coefficients are calculated:
[Original Statement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVCGA.png)
I can't seem to follow the logic.
What I have so far:
$$\frac{d}{dc} PENSSE =  \frac{d}{dc} [(y-\Phi c)'W(y-\Phi c)+\lambda c′Rc]$$
Definitions are given elsewhere in the book as:
 
$y,c$ are column vectors size k 
 
$\Phi$ is a an matrix size [n,k]
 
$W$ is, to my understanding a matrix size [k,k] by definition, and is said elsewhere to be symmetric positive definite
 
$\lambda$ is a scalar, and finally
 
$R$ is a matrix size [k,k] and is said elsewhere to be positive semidefinite.

To my understanding:
$$\frac{d}{dc} PENSSE = \frac{d}{dc} [(y-\Phi c)'W(y-\Phi c)+\lambda c'Rc]$$
$$\frac{d}{dc} PENSSE = \frac{d}{dc}[(y'W-c'\Phi'W)(y-\Phi c) \lambda c'Rc]$$
$$\frac{d}{dc} PENSSE = \frac{d}{dc}[y'Wy-c'\Phi'Wy- y'W\Phi c+c'\Phi'W\Phi c+λc′Rc]$$
Remove expression without $c$:
$$\frac{d}{dc} PENSSE = \frac{d}{dc}[-c'\Phi'Wy- y'W\Phi c+c'\Phi'W\Phi c + \lambda c'Rc]$$
Inverting the inner product that is the second term on the right does not change its result, but helps collect terms:
$$\frac{d}{dc} PENSSE = \frac{d}{dc}[-2c'\Phi'Wy+c'\Phi'W\Phi c +\lambda c'Rc]$$
$$\frac{d}{dc} PENSSE = \frac{d}{dc}[-2c'\Phi'Wy]+\frac{d}{dc}[c'\Phi'W\Phi c]+\frac{d}{dc}[\lambda c'Rc]$$
Which should, according to the text, result in:
$$-2\Phi'Wy+\Phi'W\Phi c +\lambda Rc$$

So my question, finally is as follows:
Why do the second and third term work out the way they do? The first term is easy - derivating by a vector means removing the vector. When derivating an expression with multiple occurrences of the vector, shouldn't there be a '2' in the derivative?

Edit: from proposition 9 in this [Link](https://atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf), it seems my intuition was right, and all terms should eventually have a coefficient of 2, which can be divided out. This is in line with the book's
[resultant statement:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHbkU.png)
$$c = (\Phi'W\Phi+\lambda R)^{-1}\Phi'Wy$$

Answer (score 2):

I will introduce for ease of notation, the Frobenius inner product as:

$$ A:B = \operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$$

with the following properties derivied from the underlying trace function

$$\eqalign{A:BC &= B^TA:C\cr &= AC^T:B\cr &= A^T:(BC)^T\cr &= BC:A \cr } $$

Let's use the [step](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3194760/) you already know that:

$$\eqalign{ f &= x:Ax \cr
df &= (A+A^T) : dx}$$

Thus finding the differential and gradient is strightforward.

With:
$$\eqalign{u&=(y-\Phi c) \\
du &= -\Phi dc
}$$

your function becomes:

$$\eqalign{ f &= u : Wu + \lambda c : Rc \cr
df &= (W+W^T)u : du + \lambda (R+R^T) c : dc \cr
&= (W+W^T)(y-\Phi c) : -\Phi dc + \lambda (R+R^T) c: dc \cr
&= -2W(y-\Phi c) : \Phi dc + \lambda (R+R^T) c: dc \cr
&= -2\Phi^T W (y- \Phi c) : dc + \lambda(R+R^T) c : dc  \cr
&= (-2\Phi^T Wy + 2\Phi^TW \Phi c + \lambda(R+R^T)c) : dc
}$$

Thus the gradient can be identified as:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial c} = -2\Phi^T Wy + 2\Phi^TW \Phi c + \lambda(R+R^T)c$$

Equating the gradient to zero and solving for c gives:

$$c = (2\Phi^TW\Phi + \lambda(R+R^T))^{-1} (2 \Phi^TWy) $$

In case R is also symmetric, then we can cancel the factor 2 and you get the proposed expression in your edit:

$$c = (\Phi^TW\Phi+\lambda R)^{-1}\Phi^TWy$$

Comment: Interesting! I'm not familiar with the concept of Frobenius inner product. It seems very relevant, but I'll have to spend a little bit more time taking it in. Is this the standard way to approach such derivatives, or are there other ways?
Either way - thank you very much for your reply, and I'm happy to see I was right and the error is in the book...

Comment: The final result is correct, but you have a sign error on the $\Phi^TW\Phi c$ term in the intermediate steps.

Comment: Oops. Thanks @greg, corrected.